# Switch between two databases im MVC web application

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

I'm stuck in a situation in which i have a dropdownlist that selects year(2014,2015 etc.) . based on selected value i want to connect different database in my simple MVC application. 
I have created two .edmx models (2014Demo and 2015Demo)
now if i select 2014 in dropdown then .edmx of 2014 database should be connected, if i select 2015 ,application should connect 2015 database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop using the default context connection (the one written in Web.config) and build your own connection string to create the context. `DbContext` has a `.ctor` overload that accepts a `DbConnection` as a parameter.

Comment: thanks man! just created other partial context class with same name as original context class and passed connection string to .ctor of that class